# How to Add SSL Site to Zend Server

Tags: php, apache, ssl, redhat, zend-server

I'm trying to add a secure site to Zend.

When I go to the Zend server site at http://my_IP:10081 I can see, under server extensions, 
"openssl built-in, ON".

When I add SSLEngine On to the httpd.conf I get ...

```
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined 
by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Missing this line out gives....

```
Invalid command 'SSLCertificateChainFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by 
a module not included in the server configuration.
```

Appendix F at Zend's site says

```
Uncomment the following line...
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

But that line is not in my conf file and nor is the path indicated.

The directory /usr/lib64/httpd/modules does not have a file called mod_ssl.so or similar.

This is Zend 5.5 on Red Hat

PHP Version     5.3.8-ZS5.5.0
Zend Framework Version  1.11.10

My manager says it was a pretty standard installation. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL module installed on your server may not be enabled.
Try: `sudo a2enmod ssl`

EDIT: Nvm, I guess I skipped over the part you said you were using RedHat. I don't believe there is an a2enmod equivalent in RedHat.

RedHat typically has these includes in `httpd.conf` where you will find lines like this:

`Include conf.d/*.conf`

This should corespond to an ssl configuration file located in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory. Check to make sure there is such a file and if it's configured in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. No, a2enmod wasn't recognised. The conf.d directory is there, but the SSL conf file is missing. Maybe I'll try to find a copy and add it.

Comment: Here are the contents of conf.d /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/README
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/zendserver_gui.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/zendserver_php.conf

Comment: Brilliant! Why didn't I think of that? I now get  "_default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the  first has precedence" but I'll soon sort that out. Thanks a million.

Comment: PS Just in case anyone else follows, it's mod_ssl NB the underscore.

Comment: good catch. also, the error you're getting about overlap is because you haven't configured apache to use port 443 as a vhost. add this line to your httpd.conf: `NameVirtualHost *:443`

Comment: Matt, you're a star. Thanks a lot. I'm only realising now that there's a sister site (?) for this sort of question. Sorry if it was off-topic.